# Aggregation by a compound field (copy_to) not working on Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have an index in Elasticsearch (v 1.5.0) that has a mapping that looks like this:

```
{
  "storedash": {
    "mappings": {
      "outofstock": {
        "_ttl": {
          "enabled": true,
          "default": 1296000000
        },
        "properties": {
          "CompositeSKUProductId": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Hosts": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "HostName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "SKUs": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "CompositeSKUProductId": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "Count": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "ProductId": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "copy_to": [
                      "CompositeSKUProductId"
                    ]
                  },
                  "SKU": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "copy_to": [
                      "CompositeSKUProductId"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "Timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Look at how field **CompositeSKUProductId** is created as a composition of both the SKU and ProductId fields.

I now want to perform an aggregation on *that* composite field, but it doesn't seem to work; the relevant part of my query looks like this:

```
        "aggs": {
            "hostEspecifico": {
                "filter": {
                    "term": { "Hosts.HostName": "www.example.com"}
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "skus": {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "Hosts.SKUs"
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                            "valores": {
                                "terms": { 
                                    "field": "Hosts.SKUs.CompositeSKUProductId", "order": { "media": "desc" }, "size": 100 },
                                "aggs": {
                                    "media": {
                                        "avg": {
                                            "field": "Hosts.SKUs.Count"
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Thing is**, this aggregation returned zero buckets, as though it weren't even there.

I checked that the very same query works if only I change **CompositeSKUProductId** by another field like **ProductId**.

**Any ideas as to what I can do to solve my problem?**

**N.B.:** I'm using the AWS Elasticsearch Service, which does not allow scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have misunderstood the concept of `copy_to` functionality. It simply **copies** the field values of various fields and does **not combine** the way you would expect.

If *SKU* is 123 and *product id* is 456 then composite field will have them as **separate values** and not *123 456*. You can verify this by querying your field.

You would have to do this on server side, ideally with script but it is not allowed. Personally we used AWS ES service but faced multiple problems, major being not able to change elasticsearch.yml file and not able to use scripts. You might want to look at Found.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In order to `copy_to` another field in the nested doc, you need to supply the full path to the field you want to copy to in your mapping. You have only provided "CompositeSKUProductId", which causes the data to be copied to a field in your root document, instead of your nested SKUs type document.

Try updating your mapping for your "SKUs" type to `copy_to` the fully qualified field "Hosts.SKUs.CompositeSKUProductId" instead.

Like this:

```
{
  "storedash": {
    "mappings": {
      "outofstock": {
        "_ttl": {
          "enabled": true,
          "default": 1296000000
        },
        "properties": {
          "CompositeSKUProductId": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Hosts": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "HostName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "SKUs": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "CompositeSKUProductId": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "Count": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "ProductId": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "copy_to": [
                      "Hosts.SKUs.CompositeSKUProductId"
                    ]
                  },
                  "SKU": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "copy_to": [
                      "Hosts.SKUs.CompositeSKUProductId"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "Timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may find [this discussion](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6701) helpful, when a similar issue was opened on github.